# Why doesn't the FPS print in my window?

Tags: java, loops, printing, window

I believed that the [FPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) would be printed somewhere in my new window once I started this program. I see the window but the FPS doesn't display in it. What is wrong?

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
  private Thread thread;
  private boolean running = false;

  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "MY GAME", this);
  }

  public synchronized void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
  }

  public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
      thread.join();
      running = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
      long now = System.nanoTime();
      delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = now;
      while (delta <= 1) {
        delta--;
      }
      if (running)
        frames++;

      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
        timer += 1000;
        System.out.println("fps: " + frames);
        frames = 0;
      }
    }
    stop();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this JavaFX or awt? I can't get this code to compile. Can you [edit] to include your import statements?

Comment: Where is the `run` method that is supposed to prin, being invoked? Try to call the start() and run() methods in your `Game` constructor.

Comment: import java.awt.Canvas; is the only import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial probably means that the fps will be printed out to some console window that also opened in the author's development environment. `System.out.println` will still print to standard out, unless you change it with [`setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) and write some additional code to then put or draw the text in a GUI component somewhere in your `Window`.